# Authentication backend(existing DB table is an authentication source)

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to create an authentication backend, because my usernames and passwords stores in existing DB table. In this table, there is more information than just usernames and passwords, that's why I created an extended user.

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    code = models.BigIntegerField()
    telefon = models.CharField(50)
    remark = models.CharField(250)
    fio = models.CharField(50)
```

As I understand, I don't have to include `username` and `password` in this model, because it's already included due to `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`.
OK, then I create the backend:
from login.models import MyUser

```
class AuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = MyUser.user.objects.filter(username=username)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if user.is_pass_valid(password):
            return user
        else:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = MyUser.user.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user
```

Is it all correct?
And main question: how my backend is going to return `User` object from DB table( not `auth_user` table, but existing table). I have to create models of users before authentication or what? Or I have an idea just to create such user if exists in method `authenticate`? And where should I call `get_user` method?

My idea:

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM zusers
        WHERE login = %s AND userpass = %s""", [username, password])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row:
            user = MyUser(username = row[0], password = row[1], code = row[2], telefon = row[3], remark = row[4], fio = row[5])
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: This is still nonsense. As I told you last night, there's absolutely no reason to use both inheritance and a one-to-one relationship to User or AbstractUser. AbstractUser *includes* username and password, so your model includes them too, so now you've got two versions. And if you don't want them, why are you creating a custom user at all? This is far, far simpler than you are making it.

Comment: Okay, I can do it without inheritence. But what about backend and other questions?

Comment: But none of that makes any sense either. If you want to use the username and password stored in the existing User table, what's the point of this custom backend? And if you want to use the ones stored in a separate place in the db, why have *either* User or MyUser? Why not just create a model based on your existing db table? Really I am trying my hardest to understand what you are doing, and I just can't.

Comment: One man advised me to do custom backend. I read about it in django docs, but I don't know how to implement that my auth. backend check passwords in my existing table in DB. I have an idea to do it with a query. I'm trying to do it and will show you in a few minutes. "Why not just create a model based on your existing db table? " What do you mean? Is my extended user model is not based on my db table? It contains all the attributes that my table

Comment: see updated post above.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying...you are using md5 instead of something that actually works for encrypting passwords...

If you want to extend an user it is simple since django 1.5:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    myCustomField = models.CharField()
    #You don't need ids, oneToOne or anything weird...just extra fields for your user
```

Now in settings.py or whatever your settings module is you set:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

You can find the information in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

And...thats it, you don't need anything else to make it work. Have in mind that when you are going to use your users in other models you have 2 options:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Or:

```
from myapp.models import MyUser
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
```

Using this method you don't have to worry about anything else, just forget about the default...use MyUser every time.